# Input field to accept only numbers and the number can start with 0

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield

I want the input field to only allow numbers and the number can start with 0 also. 
I tried using `ui:inputNumber` but when i click on check button for validation of input it deletes the 0 from start.
Here is my code:

```
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input slds-text-body_regular fnn-text" value="{!fnn.Name}" required="true" maxlength="10" format="########"/>
```

Early answers would be great! accept number only which can start with 0.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** numbers "cannot" start with 0. Entering something with leading zeros is a valid syntax but these will not be saved.

**Detailed answer:** any input field of type `number` (be it HTML or Lightning) will use a numeric JS type to save the data. This will strip the leading zeros.

If you need leading zeros then, what you are saving is not a number but some sort part number or a phone number. You should use a string type.

To do so, use a text input with a pattern that only allows numbers like so:

```
<lightning:input type="text" label="Numeric value" aura:id="myInput" name="myInput" pattern="[0-9]*"/>
```

This will display an error message if the user tries to enter non-numeric characters. You can check if the field is valid at any time by calling:

```
var validity = cmp.find("myInput").get("v.validity");
console.log(validity.valid);
```

**General comment for all involved in this question:** do not use `ui:inputNumber` (to be deprecated) please use `lightning:input` instead.

Comment: Loved that regex part you did -> pattern="[0-9]*

Answer (score 0):

You can an Input field and set its min attribute to zero as follows:

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

otherwise, check the ui:inputNumber's [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputNumber.htm) for available attributes. min doesn't seem to be available.

the rendered html for ui:inputNumber should resemble something like this:

```
<div class="uiInput uiInputNumber uiInput--default uiInput--input">
<label class="uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel">
    <span>Age</span>
</label>
<input max="99999999999999" step="1" type="text" 
        min="-99999999999999" class="input">
</div>
```

as per the documentation.

Comment: but when i use this <input type="number" class="slds-input slds-text-body_regular fnn-text" value="{!fnn.Name}" required="true" maxlength="10" min="0"/>  it doesnt save my value in fnn.Name and when i check in js the value is blank

Comment: update your question with the rest of your code, however, you should address this in a different post

Comment: No But the value is not getting passed to fnn.Name when i use <input>

Comment: that is an issue with your code, not the field or input tag

Comment: otherwise, you will want to validate the field value with client side logic in your controller

Comment: this is not an aura component so it is not saving the value in fnn.Name. My object is made in aura:attribute

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible through the ui:inputnumber as ui:inputnumber change the value 0345 to it's absolute value  365.

You can use the below workaround through.

You can use a ui:inputText to fetch the value from UI and then use a javascript function to check if it's a numeric value. If it's not a numeric value set your input txt to blank or the previous value.

```
<aura:attribute name="input" type="String" default="34" />
<ui:inputText value="{!v.input}" change="{!c.checkIfNotNumber}"/>
```

JS controller to check for numeric input:

```
checkIfNotNumber : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(isNaN(component.get("v.input"))){
            component.set("v.input","");
        }
    }
```